# What is $\sqrt{a+b}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

So a while back I learned that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$

So you can probably see where that's going, I just want to see what the reverse of that is.

What I've tried is this (spoiler alert, it literally goes nowhere)

$$    \sqrt{a+b} = \sqrt{(\sqrt{a^2} + \sqrt{b^2)}}\\
    a + 2\sqrt{ab} + b = (\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2\\
    \sqrt{(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2 - 2\sqrt{ab}} = \sqrt{a+b}$$

So yeah, I end up with what I started with. Which is funny yet simultaneously sad... Anyway, I feel like i'm sort of on the right track but I just can't figure it out.

I feel that, because you can work out what $(a + b)^2$ is, in terms of a and b itself, the same should be true for the square root of $a + b$.

Comment: There is an "infinite series" form of the binomial formula due to Newton.  Do you know about infinite series?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I know what you mean, as in, it applies to all powers?

Comment: What do you want to prove exactly ?

Comment: If you then make $a + b = u$, and $2\sqrt{ab}= v$ you can find an inverse in terms of u and v. Unfortunately, this comes out to a very gross formula that also has sums under square roots.

Comment: When you square $\sqrt{a+b}$, you get $a+b$, not $(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)^2$.

Comment: There are many relationships -- equations, inequalities, approximations, series expansions and so on -- that can be given that relate $\sqrt{a+b}$ to functions of $a$ and $b$ in various ways... what kind of thing did you seek?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it.  If $a$ is much larger than $b$ you can write $$\sqrt {a+b}=\sqrt a\sqrt {1+\frac ba}\approx \left(1+\frac b{2a}\right)\sqrt a$$ which can be useful.  This shows how the larger of $a,b$ dominates the square root.